# Is it possible to use a Python daemon in an Android app

Tags: android, python, python-daemon

I have a project written in Electron for frontend, which runs a Python daemon to handle heavy work in the background, for desktop.

I am looking for ways to implement a mobile version of the same project, is it possible to use python daemon affectively in Android, like Electron app did for desktop.

I've found solutions to package apps for Android that are written in Python entirely, but what I am intended to do is building an Android app and using the daemon in it.

Comment: I guess there is not or this question did not take much attention